# Opencart adds heading title in product description automatically

Tags: title, product

It is really very interesting. I am using custom template. Maybe it is interested with my template or some extensions. I am writing product description from admin panel. It is added as i write. But when i enter the product page. It adds

### product title

automatically before my description. I checked it from mysql. There is no string like this at sql. So it adds with a function. I looked at everywhere. But i couldnt find anything about this.

It is from my product.tpl

How can i remove it? Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Post some code so I can give you a full answer.
It seems as the person who created the template added it manually (maybe as a comment?) and forgot to remove it.

As you implied, you need to edit product.tpl and remove it manually.
My guess is that a simple text search for 'product title' will find the problem.

If not - please post some code so we can look.